# Runtime exception on MediaRecorder.stop() function in android

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediaprojection

I am creating a Screen Capturing App. Using MediaRecorder with MediaProjection API.

> Getting Run-time Exception while stopping the recorder

Here is the code to stop Screen Capture

```
private void stop_recorder() {

    if (virtualDisplay == null) {
        return;
    }

    virtualDisplay.release();

    if (mediaProjection != null) {
        mediaProjection.unregisterCallback(projectionCallback);
        mediaProjection.stop();
        mediaProjection = null;
    }

    if (recorder != null) {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.reset();

    }

}
```

The Exception occur is

> `E/MediaRecorder: stop failed: -1007
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed.
>       at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)`

Comment: add full log cat

Answer (score 0):

> **The Issue is with the emulator. It does not have audio and video source.**

[Look android.developer doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#stop())

> RuntimeException is intentionally thrown to the application, if no valid audio/video data has been received when stop() is called. This happens if stop() is called immediately after start().

**Solution**

> Put the **mediaRecorder.stop()** function in **try-catch** block